# Including MVC in existing Sitecore Project

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

we have a Sitecore Project up and running, that is based on the regular aspx/ascx approach.

Over time we would like to transform our existing sublayouts to MVC.

For test purposes I am trying to add a very simple MVC text component to the project, still I am stuck somehow.

What I have done so far:

- Installed MVC 5.2
- Installed WebPages
- Added references and bindings
- Added the MVC Scaffold

Right now, the Site does compile and run.

I have this Controller:

```
    public class TextComponentController : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
        return View();
      }
    }
```

And my view:

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>Hello from my View Template</p>
```

So absolutely nothing special here ;)

How can I create a sublayout (without a datasource) that just displays this simple MVC component?

Comment: Have you created a controller rendering in Sitecore?

Comment: Not yet, but yes I have now seen that you can add a view rendering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the very simplest way, you need to have the following:

1. **Item** for your page, the one that has URL; that is as normal in Sitecore
2. That page Item should have **Layout** assigned. From **Presentation** **-->** **Details** menu select at least a layout on that stage. If you do not have layout yet, you need to create a layout definition item under **/Layout/Layouts** folder and associate it with certain *.cshml file. Also mention that layout should have a placeholder where you will "inject"your rendering.

   ```
   @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("Main")
   ```
3. You need to create a Controller Rendering under **/Layout/Renderings** folder in Sitecore. Make sure you set **Controller** and **Controller Action** fields to your controller name and action method name.
   [image]
4. Finally, go again to **Presentation --> Details --> Edit --> Controls** and add your newly created rendering into a placeholder that you have on your layout *.cshtml file.
   [image]

That's all done.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Martin I will  try that now. Do the Model/Views/Controller Folders need to be in the root of my website or can I store the views and controllers whereever I want? We are using Subfolders for different kind of content components. For Example Website/layouts/projectName/Footer

Comment: Controllers are just normal .NET classes that are compiler into DLL and are resolved by Sitecore on runtime. You can place them wherever you want on your code; same applies for classical MVC

Comment: Thank you Martin. But Sitecore seems to Search for a View in Website/Views. How to change that?

Comment: Easy =))  return View("/your/view/path");

Comment: Thanks Martin, is there a way to include my mvc component inside my exisitng MainLayout(aspx file) or do I have to rewrite it?

Comment: This is exctly what step (4) from my explanation does - asigning your rendering to a page (represented with a layout). I looks like you need to get more understanding on how Sitecore and MVC works, I would advise you to search youtube for "Sitecore MVC" there should be multiple exact tutorials

Comment: Hi Martin. I was able to follow your steps, and now I have a working mvc textcomponent. I was just asking me if there is a way to add this component to a legacy <sc:placeholder>. I have seen that I can use my existing static sublayouts by using Html.RenderPartial("NameOfTheSublayout"). But can I add View Renderings to my existing placeholders?

Comment: <sc:placeholder> is not MVC, that is webforms (while you've mentioned you are working on MVC 5.2 project). You can have both WebForms and MVC on the same website. You can even place your old webform sublayouts into your MVC page (with couple of hacks), but not the reverse.

Comment: Thanks martin, you saved my day. Please note until now I have only used a view rendering, I will try to build the same now with a controller rendering, and then I will rebuild my mainlayout with MVC. Thanks again.